# Can't write files with Android DocumentsProvider

Tags: android

I have an Android DocumentsProvider that I can read through using apps that support Androids Storage Access Framework.  Apps such as Word, and Google's own DocumentsUI.  I cannot write files to the DocumentsProvider.  Anything that writes to the store, be it renames, deletes, create files, or file writes will fail before the request even makes it to the Documents Provider.

My provider section of my `AndroidManifest.xml` looks like:

```
<provider android:name="com.mycompany.myproduct.myprovider"
android:authorities="com.mycompany.myproduct.documents"
android:grantUriPermissions="true"
android:exported="true"
android:permission="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.content.action.DOCUMENTS_PROVIDER"/>
  </intent-filter>
</provider>
```

My provider is part of an app that has the following `permissions`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

When I return rows from the storage provider, I include the `FLAGS_SUPPORTS_WRITE, FLAGS_SUPPORTS_DELETE, FLAGS_SUPPORTS_RENAME`.

I wonder if this is not an issue with the DocumentsProvider as much as the app that initiates the intent.  But it seems that those apps are able to write to other providers.  So, I'm wondering if I'm missing something obvious (or subtle, I don't care which).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I worked on this issue for a couple of days.  Could of sworn that it used to work.  The fact that it worked for read but not for write stumped me.  Anyway, after auditing the provider closely, I found one thing that wasn't right.

> call
>   added in API level 19
>   public Bundle call (String method, 
>                   String arg, 
>                   Bundle extras)
>   Implementation is provided by the parent class. Can be overridden to provide 
>   additional functionality, but subclasses must always call the superclass. If the > superclass returns null, the subclass may implement custom behavior.
>
> If you override this method you must call through to the superclass 
>   implementation.

I had recently added a call into the provider so I implemented this call routine but... without the call to super.  Everything else works, so it doesn't stand out in any particular way other than writes don't work.  There must be some call, probably associated with permissions, that must get passed to the base class.  I was blocking it.  So, consider this solved.